# Python : how to get the text in <li> using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Here is the html file I am going to handle:

```
<ul class="canTouch" data-com="hrefTo,href:'/movie/246286?_v_=yes'">
    <li class='c1'>
        <b>Important text</b>
        <br><em>useless text </em><em style="margin-left: .1rem">useless text</em>
    </li>
    <li class="c2 ">
        <b>938.6</b><br/>
    </li>
    <li class="c3 ">19.7%</li>
    <li class="c4 ">19.6%</li>
    <li class="c5 ">
        <span style="margin-right:-.1rem">8.6%</span>
        <span style="padding-right:.24rem" class="_more"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are many `ul` tags in the file, and here is my code:

```
for ul in soup.find_all('ul')[3:]:
lis=ul.find_all('li')
for elem in lis:
    records.append(elem.text.strip())
```

I don't want the useless text in the `em` tags of the `li` but I need the important text in the `b` tag:

```
<li class='c1'>
    <b>Important text</b>
    <br><em>useless text<em style="margin-left: .1rem">useless text</em>
 </li>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you want to scrape data only from the first `li` tag or all the `li` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change is going to be trivial, replace:

```
records.append(elem.text.strip())
```

with:

```
records.append(elem.b.text.strip())
```